# Weird folder keeps appearing in the internal memory

Tags: file-system

I have a *Redmi Note 3* Pro handset (2 years old) in which I am using AOSP Custom ROM (Android 8.1). For last 1 year, a weird empty folder is getting created randomly on my internal memory. I generally delete it if I notice it, but it again appears after few days. It does not do any visible harm in my device, but I want to know who is creating this folder and find out if their is any harmful process running all the time.

Throughout the last year, I have wiped my system, data, cache, delvik-cache partition several times for flashing different Custom Rom. But this folder never left me. Is their any way to monitor the internal memory to find out who (which app) is creating this folder when it will do the same next time? Or is there any system-log where I can find it out ? I have *Root-access* on my mobile and I can confirm that I have never given a suspicious app root-access. Most importantly, this folder is popping up from the time when I used to have my Stock MIUI Rom and no root access.

Here is a Screenshot with the concerned folder marked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the folder which many developers use to store the image cache while parsing a json.

As can be seen from the folder name, the folder was introduced in some sort of tutorial or demo given to the developers who are trying to parse json in their apps. However, the takers of the tutorial continued to use the same code in their apps.

There's nothing to worry about this folder. It is just for caching the images and I believe it makes room in a number of Android apps.